# Каким образом получить новый массив из текущего?

Tags: php

Через переменную получаю такой массив вывода продукта

```
array(4) {
  [0]=>
  array(3) {
    ["name"]=>
    string(58) "Адаптер прямоугольного сечения"
    ["price"]=>
    string(8) "300 руб."
    ["catID"]=>
    string(1) "7"
    ["catName"]=>
    string(60) "Воздуховоды квадратного сечения"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(3) {
    ["name"]=>
    string(43) "Воздуховод прямошовный"
    ["price"]=>
    string(8) "500 руб."
    ["catID"]=>
    string(1) "8"
    ["catName"]=>
    string(54) "Воздуховоды круглого сечения"
  }
  [2]=>
  array(3) {
    ["name"]=>
    string(51) "Врезка круглая в воздуховод"
    ["price"]=>
    string(8) "60 руб."
    ["catID"]=>
    string(1) "8"
    ["catName"]=>
    string(54) "Воздуховоды круглого сечения"
  }
  [3]=>
  array(14) {
    ["name"]=>
    string(56) "Заглушка воздуховода торцевая"
    ["price"]=>
    string(8) "900 руб."
    ["catID"]=>
    string(1) "7"
    ["catName"]=>
    string(60) "Воздуховоды квадратного сечения"
  }
}
```

В данном примере 3 продукта относиться к категории №7 ( catID) а один к №8
Задача, вывести по категориям, что бы на странице формировалась такая структура

```
<div class="category-wrap">

    <div class="category-name"><span>Названия категории №1</span></div>
    <div class="category-products">
      <div class="category-product">
        <div class="category-product__name">Имя продукта</div>
        <div class="category-product-price">Цена продукта</div>
      </div>
      <div class="category-product">
        <div class="category-product__name">Имя продукта</div>
        <div class="category-product-price">Цена продукта</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="category-wrap">

    <div class="category-name"><span>Названия категории №2</span></div>
    <div class="category-products">
      <div class="category-product">
        <div class="category-product__name">Имя продукта</div>
        <div class="category-product-price">Цена продукта</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Я подумал сделать следующим образом. Пройтись по массиву, и сравнивать ID категории, создавая новые массивы , где каждый массив будет иметь названия категории, ид, и внутри массив с продукции которые относяться к данной категории. По логике понимаю как сделать но возникли трудности с реализации. Буду очень признателен за помощь.

Comment: покажите вашу реализацию

Answer (score 0):

```
$items =[
    ['name'=>'Адаптер прямоугольного сечения1','price'=>12,'catID'=>'7','catName'=>'Воздуховоды квадратного сечения'],
    ['name'=>'Адаптер прямоугольного сечения2','price'=>13,'catID'=>'7','catName'=>'Воздуховоды квадратного сечения'],
    ['name'=>'Адаптер прямоугольного сечения3','price'=>14,'catID'=>'7','catName'=>'Воздуховоды квадратного сечения'],
    ['name'=>'Врезка круглая в воздуховод1','price'=>15,'catID'=>'8','catName'=>'Воздуховоды круглого сечения'],
    ['name'=>'Врезка круглая в воздуховод2','price'=>16,'catID'=>'8','catName'=>'Воздуховоды круглого сечения'],
    ['name'=>'Врезка круглая в воздуховод3','price'=>17,'catID'=>'8','catName'=>'Воздуховоды круглого сечения'],
];

$result = [];
foreach($items as $item){
    $catId = $item['catID'];
    $result[$catId]['catID'] = $item['catID'];
    $result[$catId]['catName'] = $item['catName'];
    unset($item['catID'],$item['catName']);
    $result[$catId]['items'][] = $item ;
}
var_dump($result);
```